# how to write regex for a price expression?

Tags: python, regex

Expression is : "price(might contain comma) EG"

Examples:

```
40 EG
```

OR

```
4,657 EG
```

OR

```
4,352,345 EG
```

I want one string regex I should use for all of these cases.

Comment: Is this a valid input: `12345 EG`? How about `1,23,4567,444,5 EG`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one:

```
^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\sEG$
```

If you want decimals as well...

```
^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d?)?\sEG$
```

---

Now, if you can have numbers (more than 999) without commas at all and with possible decimal...

```
^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d\d?)?\sEG$
```

---

More details:

`^` at the start means that the price must start with the next character (here `\d` meaning a numeric character)

`\d{1,3}` means 1 to 3 numeric characters.

`(,\d{3})*` is a group, appearing 0 times or more, consisting of a comma and 3 numeric characters. Assuming that the price you get is 'clean', things like `,34` in a price like `3,34 EG` won't be allowed through.

`(\.\d\d?)?` is another group, appearing 0 or 1 time, consisting of a period `.`, a digit and a second possible digit. Things like `.2` or `.54` are allowed. `.564` is not, however.

`\s` means one space character, and no more, no less. If the price data you are given is 'clean', there should be no issue and will actually help you identify those that are not 'clean'.

`EG` simply matches the currency `EG`.

`$` means that the preceding character (`G` in this case) has to be the last one.

Comment: Your third example `^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d\d?)?\sEG$` will match with `1000,000,000`.

Comment: @jvallver that was the purpose: if the commas weren't always 'there'. I don't know how messy the actual values can be, but assuming a clean one, I would go for 1st or 2nd regexp. 3rd gives some freedom for possible 'messiness' with the comma.

Comment: ok, but I think is best you have to choose whether to format the prices with commas or without any comma. The mixt of 4+ digits and commas is a bit strange.

Comment: @jvallver yup, me too, that's why it's not my first or second option :) I thought about it a bit later on, but the OP hasn't been around to confirm anything yet, so I added it just in case ^^ The purpose of the regex hasn't been given either; is it to accept only these so the ones not conforming to the pattern can be identified, or is the pattern used only to be able to use the numbers at a later stage, as long as they are usable? So... =/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
"([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*)\s+EG"
```

If your number can not have commas, for example `123456`. you can use this alternative:

```
"([0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*)\s+EG"
```

Comment: Two minor issues: I'd use `\s+` just in case, and some reasonable limit like `{0,5}` instead of `*` - they definitely don't want that to match gazillions pounds.

Comment: @thg435 thanks for the comment. You are right, I edited for using \s+.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: `/(?:\d,?)+\sEG/`

That will match any of those price strings.

**Edit**: This is the most comprehensive one I can think of right now.

`[^\.,\d](?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?\s*EG`

This will match:

```
123,123,123EG
234,123.23 EG
234123 EG
234123.52 EG
```

And will not match:

```
,,,,, EG
1,2,3,4,5,6 EG
1234,123 EG
234,1234 EG
```

Comment: But this will match 1,2,3,4 too.

Comment: Sure, and it will also match 1234 EG.  The OP says it "might" contain commas.  Unless there is a specific reason to only want values in the format of `/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\sEG/` (which will not match 1234 EG), I would use the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
import re
t = ["40 EG",
"4,657 EG",
"4,352,345 EG",
",,,,,, EG",
"1,2,3,4 EG",
 "12345 EG"]

regex = "[\d{1,3},]+\d{3}\sEG|^\d+\sEG"

for string in t:
    print re.findall(regex, string)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['40 EG']
['4,657 EG']
['4,352,345 EG']
[]
[]
['12345 EG']
```

EDIT: Have updated to meet requirements exactly, see above

Comment: This will also match `,,,,,, EG`, is that what the OP wants?

Comment: Your answer will match "1,2,3,4 EG" expression

Comment: Have changed regex to stop @JackAidley's case

Comment: Updated to match the requirements exactly

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9]{1,3}(?:\,[0-9]{3})*|(?:[0-9]+))(?:\.([0-9]{2}))?(?=\s{1,}EG)`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, pprint

strings = ['40 EG', '4,657 EG', '1234 EG', '6,78 EG', '4,352,345 EG', '1,234']
csn = re.compile('\d{1,3}(,\d{3})* EG')
pprint.pprint( [(s, bool(csn.match(s))) for s in strings] )

[('40 EG', True),
 ('4,657 EG', True),
 ('1234 EG', False),
 ('6,78 EG', False),
 ('4,352,345 EG', True),
 ('1,234', False)]
```